# How to use regexp in sqlite

Tags: regex, android-sqlite

Please prompt, how used REGEXP in SQLite?

Realization:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '123'
```

It is not working. `Error: no such function: REGEXP`

Answer (score 12):

Currently am working on sqlite3+php for my web application in Ubuntu 12.04. I was also faced the same issue then after research i had found that we need to install one pcre package for sqlite3. Here we go how to

1. `apt-get install sqlite3-pcre`
2. Then go to sqlite3 command line `sqlite3 test.db`
3. run the command `.load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so`
4. test : `SELECT url  FROM table_name where url REGEXP '^google.*';`

After following those 3 steps its working fine for me.
If am wrong regarding this please correct me. 
I hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: any idea how to do this with windows?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use it.

First, you'd need a function that implements it, as per [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(Y,X)".

There's no way to install user-defined functions in Android SQLite.

Consider whether you can write your regex as a `GLOB` or `LIKE` pattern instead.

Comment: There is a way to install user-defined functions in Android SQLite with NDK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sqlean-regexp`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/regexp.md) extension, which provides regexp search and replace functions.

Based on the PCRE2 engine, this extension supports all major regular expression features. It also supports Unicode.

The extension is available for Windows, Linux, and macOS. You could probably build it for Android using [`android-gcc-toolchain`](https://github.com/sjitech/android-gcc-toolchain).