# SQL, putting together LIKE queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
SELECT name
FROM TV
WHERE name LIKE '%Day%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%Days%'
            AND name NOT LIKE '%Hayday%'
            AND name NOT LIKE '%Payday%'
            AND name NOT LIKE '%Doomsday%'
```

How could I merge the last 3 queries so that the word 'day' is not included in any word except for a word on its own?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are a part of a string... assuming that you're searching inside a phrase, 
Or at the beginning or end of it. This is a simple case solution, assuming no punctuations, just texts and spaces.
then a solution should be something like:

```
SELECT name
FROM Track
WHERE name (name  LIKE '% Day %') OR (name  LIKE '% Day') OR (name  LIKE 'Day %')
;
```

Comment: Will miss "Another time."

Comment: How come ? (and anyway, the question was edited to search for "days"...)

Comment: Still won't match "Another Day."

Comment: Why ? its either with a space after the y, or no character at all

Comment: Who's to say there isn't punctuation as @jarlh pointed out in his original comment?

Comment: took me a little bit, but I got it...:) you're right. I'll add a remark to my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL, you can use [RLIKE (REGEXP)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to match only against the word by itself by creating an expression with word boundaries:

```
SELECT name
FROM TV
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Day[[:>:]]'
```

Note that `REGEXP` is case-insenstive so this will also match the word "day".

If you are using SQLite, it is possible you have `REGEXP` installed in which case this solution should work for you too. If not, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037982/how-to-use-regexp-in-sqlite) gives guidance as to how you may be able to install it.

Comment: And none of the other answers using `LIKE` can do what your query is doing.  Maybe add a comment that `REGEXP` is case insensitive.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen indeed. Unforuntately SQLite doesn't have REGEXP installed by default.

Comment: No...but it might also support `REGEXP`, which still helps your answer even in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, instead of 'Like' keyword, you can directly give the string like 
    "`where name ='time'`

Answer (score 0):

You can by using  FIND_IN_SET

```
SELECT name
FROM Track
WHERE name LIKE '%Time%'
AND FIND_IN_SET(name,"Times,Playtime,Summertime,Wartime")<0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "on its own" you mean surrounded by spaces, then the simplest method might be:

```
SELECT name
FROM TV
WHERE ' ' || name || ' ' LIKE '% Day %';
```

(Or however your database does string concatenation.)

If "on its own" simply means a word boundary, then regular expressions are the best method.